# Grab the domain the HTML5 game is running on. Libgdx

Tags: html, libgdx

It's possible to grab the local domain/ip the HTML5 game is running on? Framework is Libgdx.

Comment: I don't know how much control you have using libgdx, but you can get the domain using window.location.host , or window.location.hostname in javascript

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is possible to use gwt libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive the local domain in Libgdx it is possible to use `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.Location`.